# Is there a way to call Wordpress posts into a Bigcommerce store?

Tags: wordpress, api, bigcommerce

I'm developing a theme on Bigcommerce using the new Stencil framework. I'm using the Cornerstone theme, and I need to call posts from a Wordpress site into it,

How would be the best way to do this? I've done this before but only with two sites on Wordpress, any recommendations would be much appreciated,

Here is the site I'm working on - http://jgs4x41.mybigcommerce.com/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use free app please check it

https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/blog-sync/
or you can find  here something like you need
http://inkblotdigital.com/2014/wordpress-blog-bigcommerce-store/